# Could not connect to the Game Center Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center, gamekit

I am trying to integrate Game Centre to my Sprite Kit game. I am referring to this link:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/

I have created a record on my iTunes Connect account for the game I am building. I try connecting to the Game Centre in the Simulator by trying to login through the Game Centre App itself and it gives me this error:

**Could not Connect to the Game Center Server**

And if I try to login through settings > Game Center, I get an error saying:

**Unable to connect to server,

The network connection was lost**

When I open my game, I have code written which checks if there is an authenticated user or not, and if not, it shows up the login to game centre scene. It showed this a couple of times but I canceled it because I kept getting the first error. Now that screen doesn't even show up.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have Game Centre enabled in my game in the capabilities menu.

EDIT:
This is in my viewController.m:

-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer {

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
            gameCenterEnabled = YES;

            // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else{
                    leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                }
            }];
        }

        else{
            gameCenterEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
};
```

}

I call it in the viewDidLoad of my viewController.m

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Which part of the code should I edit?

Comment: The login code. Also please put in the tags the language you are using (Swift or Objective-C).

Comment: I have added the login code, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be with your device and not your code. Try these steps:

Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button together for at least ten seconds, until the Apple logo appears.

If that doesn't help, tap Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings.

You will have to re-enter your WiFi password.

Also confirm your device Apple ID matches your developer ID.

Comment: I am running it on the iOS Simulator. iPhone 6, iOS 8.1

Comment: @RohanKalantri - Then the issue might be your firewall not allowing a connection.

Comment: I have Xcode set for "Allow incoming connections in firewall" is this how it should be or should I try turning off firewall altogether?

Comment: @RohanKalantri - Your firewall is set via your computer. System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall. Try turning your firewall off (if it's on) and run your app again.

Comment: A few things here: Apple ID doesn't really have to match developer ID. OP could be using a sandbox account. The network settings do not really matter at all in this case. I do agree it's something connected with the device/app settings and not the code itself though.

Comment: I tried doing this:  
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

I do not get an option for reset all settings. Still gives the same error